# How to show percentage change in bar plot in Python pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

here is a simple bar plot :

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [10, 45, 23]

plt.bar(x, y)
```

I just want to show the percentage change from one bar to another. Maybe you can help. Thanks

Comment: Is your question still open?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) function (matplotlib 3.4.2):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [10, 45, 23]

bars = plt.bar(x, y, fc='crimson', ec='navy')
plt.bar_label(bars, [''] + [f'{(y1 - y0) / y0 * 100:+.2f}%' for y0, y1 in zip(y[:-1], y[1:])])
plt.margins(y=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot with percentage change]